# how to display image in angular saved on node server

Tags: node.js, angular

I have a nodejs app running on localhost:3000, I uploaded images using multer, so they are in ./uploads/ folder. In the Angular app running on locahost:4200 I want to retrieve those images.

in my for loop:

```html
<tr *ngFor="let data of empData;let i=index">
    <td>{{i+1}}</td>
    <td>{{data.emp_name}}</td>
    <td><img src="./uploads/{{data.emp_image}}"></td>
</tr>
```

I have all data in following result variable:

```js
this.emp.viewData().subscribe(
  res => {
    this.empData = res;
  },
  err => {
    console.log(err);
  },
)
```

Comment: you have to append the folder or bucket path before the data value to access the image 
like http(s)://localhost:8080/src/images/data.value

Comment: Can u explain more or give a example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the answer above by Software Person, ensure you include this to you node application to enable you access the uploads directory in your nodejs application.

```
const express   = require('express');
const app       = express();

app.use(express.static('uploads'));
```

Happy Coding.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You could include your full url like

```html
<tr *ngFor="let data of empData;let i=index">
    <td>{{i+1}}</td>
    <td>{{data.emp_name}}</td>
    <td><img src="http(s)://localhost:3000/uploads/{{data.emp_image}}"></td>
</tr>
```

Or even better you could define a variable in component and use it like this:

```html
<tr *ngFor="let data of empData;let i=index">
    <td>{{i+1}}</td>
    <td>{{data.emp_name}}</td>
    <td><img src="{{SERVER_UPLOAD_DIR}}/{{data.emp_image}}"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Could you add the code of your component and try access the url in your browser if you can access it that way

Comment: I have access the url through browser it gives the error as follows:

`Cannot GET /uploads/emp_img-1562410462956.png`

Comment: A 404 I guess, Which means you have uploaded it to a non-public folder. Could you provide your nodejs implementation and your folder structure. So I can give you a solution (just edit your original)

Comment: Thank u sir, I have fixed it.